# API call isn't DeserializeObject when return

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core

I have my baseService.cs that calls the given API Url. I hits the API and get the Data back no problem. When I pass the Json objects to the `DeserializeObject` method it doesn't populate the `Result` as needed to send it back to the controller method. I feel that I'm missing a simple step here to get this working. If there is any code you would like to see more of please let me know.

```
HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = null; 

apiResponse = await client.SendAsync(message);

var apiContent = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var APIResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(apiContent);

return APIResponse;
```

this is what the `var apiContent` data looks like

[image: what the return Json data looks like]

Here is the `var APIResponse` data.. as you can see everything is null.

[image]

Here is the `APIResponse` class looks like

```
public class APIResponse
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; } = true;
    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }
    public object Result { get; set; }      
}
```

Here is the APIRequest

```
public class APIRequest
{
    public ApiType ApiType { get; set; } = ApiType.GET;
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> List()
{
  BlogPostListModel list = new();
  var response = await _blogService.GetAllAsync<APIResponse>();
```

BlogService

```
public Task<T> GetAllAsync<T>()
{
    return SendAsync<T>(new APIRequest()
    { 
            ApiType = SD.ApiType.GET, 
            Url = blogUrl + "/api/Blog/List"            
    }); 
}
```

BlogPostListModel

```
public class BlogPostListModel : BaseEntityModel
{
    public BlogPostListModel()
    {
        PagingFilteringContext = new BlogPagingFilteringModel();
        BlogPost = new List<BlogPostModel>(); 
    }

    public BlogPagingFilteringModel PagingFilteringContext { get; set; }
    public IList<BlogPostModel> BlogPost { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your `apiContent` looks like a `BlogPostListModel`, but you are trying to deseriaize that into an `APIResponse` object. As there is no match for the deserialization, all the fields set to null.

Answer (score 0):

`apicontent` is type of `BlogPostListModel`. It should just be the `result` of you custom response type `APIResponse`.
The properties of `APIResponse` need to be assigned manualy from `HttpResponseMessage` properties.

```
            HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = null;

            apiResponse = await client.SendAsync(message);

            var apiContent = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            APIResponse APIResponse = new APIResponse
            {
                StatusCode = apiResponse.StatusCode,
                IsSuccess = apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode,
                ErrorMessages = apiContent,     //I'm not sure why List<string> errors
                Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlogPostListModel>(apiContent)
            };



            return APIResponse;
```